# Is it possible to run excel macros in linux?

Tags: linux, excel

Ideally this is a python-specific question but my findings so far are negative. So I would like to generalize it to seek a way to run Excel VBA macros in linux environment.

What are the actual limitations if it is impossible?

Comment: Have you tried running any in LibreOffice or OpenOffice or any of the other office suites?

Comment: I’ve answered similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66883194/how-to-run-excel-macros-using-python-in-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is a Microsoft product and doesn't run on Linux.

There is some support for VB outside of Windows [via the Mono project](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/).

We don't know what you're trying to accomplish but it would without doubt be easier, cleaner, and more feasible to stick to Linux programs and tools, e.g. Python and LibreOffice/OpenOffice.

Comment: Excel runs on MacOS

Comment: @WestHamster True, I did not think of that.  Good point.